# Remove last character in get_post_meta

Tags: post-meta

I have a custom field that contains a sentence along with a punctuation mark at the end. I am looking to use this field as a title of the article on my homepage, but in doing so I would like to remove the last character of that custom field (so that the ending period of the sentence is not included in the title).

**Here is the code I use to display the custom field on my homepage:**

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, one_line_summary, true); ?>
```

I'm not great with PHP programming, so specific examples with my code would be preferred. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a *PHP* question then a WordPress question.

If you want to remove [punctuation marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation) like (`.,-;:`) you can try this recursive version:

```
$s = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'one_line_summary', TRUE );

if( function_exists( 'remove_punctuation_marks' ) )
    $s = remove_punctuation_marks( $s );
```

with

```
/**
 * Remove punctuation marks (.,-;:) if they're the last characters in the string
 * WPSE: 119519
 *
 * @param string $s
 * @return string $s
 */
function remove_punctuation_marks( $s )
{
    $remove = array( '.', ',', '-', ';', ':' );          // Edit this to your needs 
    if( in_array( mb_substr( $s, -1 ), $remove, TRUE ) )
        $s = remove_punctuation_marks( mb_substr( $s, 0, -1 ) ); 

    return $s;    
}
```

where you can define `$remove` to your needs and `mb_substr()` is a multi-byte version of `substr()`.

### Example:

The following test:

```
echo  remove_punctuation_marks( '...Hello world...:,;' );
```

gives the output:

```
...Hello world
```

### Update:

It's better to use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) as @toscho pointed out ;-)

Then in your case:

```
$s = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'one_line_summary', TRUE ); 
$s = rtrim( $s, '.,;:' );
```

where you can add to the list (`.,;:`) of punctuation marks to remove.

Comment: You couldn’t find `rtrim()`? :)

Comment: ...not the first time reinventing the wheel happens or the last time, in my case, thanks ;-)

Comment: Sorry I do not know anything about `rtrim()` any way you could give me an example of how to do it my `get_post_meta` example inside a loop in Wordpress?

Comment: sure, please check out the updated answer.

Comment: It worked using your help from above, full line is here: `<?php $s = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'one_line_summary', TRUE ); $s = rtrim( $s, '.,;:!?' ); echo $s ?>`

Comment: great to hear that, good luck with your project - cheers